# Android access XML constants actual value in code

Tags: java, android, xml, constants

In XML I defined two constants like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="toast_x">10</integer>
    <integer name="toast_y">100</integer>
</resources>
```

But when I access in a code like below

```
int xco = R.integer.toast_x;
int yco = R.integer.toast_y;
```

I am getting weird value 2131296257 and 2131296258 respectively

I know those are HEX value.

But I just want to access actual value i.e 10 and 100

Please let me know that how can I achieve this....

Comment: You are retrieving the **id** of the constant, not its **value**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to get integer resource value:

```
int xco = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.toast_x);
int yco = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.toast_y);
```

Answer (score 2):

actually you need Context too if you trying to access the value from outside Activity

```
class boo{
   public static void foo(Context con){
      int xco = con.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.toast_x);
      int yco = con.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.toast_y);
   }
}
```

getResources() function inside Context
so here fun to access value from out side Activity

```
class boo{
   public static int foo(Context con,int resId){
      return con.getResources().getInteger(resId);
   }
}
```

Comment: @@NoXSaeeD, Good design pattern!

Answer (score 0):

Define both toast_x and toast_y in  tag of their own.

```
  <resources>
     <string name="toast_x">10</string>
     <string name="toast_y">100</string>
  </resources>
```

Now come to your java class
 and read them as strings and then convert them to integers.

```
String xcostr = getString(R.string.toast_x);
int xco = Integer.valueOf(xcostr);

String ycostr = getString(R.string.toast_y);
int yco = Integer.valueOf(ycostr);
```

Comment: why you wanna save it as string if you want integers! then after that converting

Comment: I am trying to make things clear to the guy who asked this question, I guess he is an android beginner.